# Rationale of restrictive rules for extract and re-insert with map

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, undefined-behavior

Since C++17, [associative containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) support the extraction of a node and its re-insertion (possibly into another container of the same type). The object returned by `extract(key)` is a [*node_handle*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle), which is move-only and for map containers has member functions

```
key_type &key() const;
mapped_type &mapped() const;
```

which allow to alter not only the mapped type, but also the key. This can be used to change the key **without re-allocation** (example taken from the [documentation for `map::extract()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract)):

```
std::map<int, std::string> map{{1,"mango"}, {2,"papaya"}, {3,"guava"}};
auto handle = map.extract(2);
handle.key() = 4;
map.insert(move(handle));
```

As far as I understand, `map` is implemented as binary-search tree, while `map::extract()` un-links a node from the tree and returns a pointer to it via the node-handle, which takes over the ownership. Upon `map::insert()`, the node is re-linked into the tree and ownership is taken over by the map again.

Thus, the node (and the stored `key` and `mapped_type`) are not re-allocated, moved, or copied in the process. The [standard says](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#10) (my high lighting):

> The extract members invalidate only iterators to the removed element;
>   pointers and references to the removed element remain valid. However,
>   accessing the element through such pointers and references while the
>   element is owned by a node_­type is **undefined behavior**. References and
>   pointers to an element obtained while it is owned by a node_­type are
>   **invalidated** if the element is successfully inserted.

**My question:** what is the rationale behind (1) making it UB to access an extracted element by its address and (2) invalidating upon insertion the address taken in the extracted state?

IMHO, this extract-and-insert idiom can be implemented in a way that keeps the address of the element valid at all times (until destruction, which may occur before map-destruction if the element is never re-inserted). The following code

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct immovable_string : std::string
{
    immovable_string(const char*s) : std::string(s) {}
    immovable_string() = default;
    immovable_string(immovable_string const&) = delete;
    immovable_string(immovable_string &&) = delete;
    immovable_string&operator=(immovable_string const&) = delete;
    immovable_string&operator=(immovable_string &&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int,immovable_string> map;

    map.emplace(1,"mango");
    map.emplace(2,"papaya");
    map.emplace(3,"guava");

    std::cout << "initially:     "
              << " address=" << std::addressof(map[2])
              << " value=" << map[2] <<'\n';

    auto handle = map.extract(2);

    std::cout << "after extract: "
              << " address=" << std::addressof(handle.mapped())
              << " value=" << handle.mapped() <<'\n';

    handle.key() = 4;
    map.insert(move(handle));

    std::cout << "after insert:  "
              << " address=" << std::addressof(map[4])
              << " value=" << map[4] <<'\n';
}
```

compiles (with gcc 8.2.0 using `-std=c++17`) and gives output

```
initially:      address=0x7f9e06c02738 value=papaya
after extract:  address=0x7f9e06c02738 value=papaya
after insert:   address=0x7f9e06c02738 value=papaya
```

as expected (the same results are obtained for `std::string` in place of `immovable_string` and/or `unordered_map` instead of `map`).

---

**Edit**

Note that I'm **not asking** about issues related to modifying the `key` (`map` stores `pair<const Key,T>`).

My question is solely about restrictions for access to the mapped element  via pointers or references. The whole idea of the extract-and-insert idiom makes *only* sense if the element is not moved/copied, i.e. if its address remains valid at all times (which in fact is specified by the standard). Rendering access to the element whilst in the extracted state UB seems strange and **renders the extract-and-insert mechanism less useful**: think about multi-threaded code with one thread accessing an element whilst another extracts and re-inserts it. This can be implemented w/o any issue yet may invoke UB -- **WHY?**

Here is a UB scenario (which IMHO is perfectly fine, no UB required):

```
void somefunc(object*ptr) { ptr->do_something(); }
void re_key(map<int,object> &M, int oldKey, int newKey)
{
    if(M.find(0)!=M.end() && M.find(newKey)==M.end()) {
        auto handle = M.extract(0);
        handle.key() = newKey;
        M.insert(std::move(handle));
    }
}

map<int,object> M = fillMap();
auto ptr = addressof(M[0]);     // takes initial address
thread t1(somefunc,ptr);        // uses said address to access object
thread t2(re_key,M,7);          // extracts and inserts an object
```

Of course, if the `insert()` fails, the `handle` is destroyed and the address invalidated. That's obvious, but the user can to something about that.

Answer (score 12):

I think the predominant subtlety in the "extraction" system is that the `value_type` of a `map<K, T>` is `pair<const K, T>` — note the `const`!

Modifying a const object causes undefined behaviour, so you need to be very careful not to modify something that's known to be const. While the node is part of any map, the key is const. The "magic" of the extraction machinery (and the reason it took so long to specify) is that *while the node is extracted*, the key is *not* const.

This basically requires you to look at the problem really hard and convince yourself that a `pair<const K, T>` can sometimes be interpreted as a `pair<K, T>` (and bear in mind that `pair` is a template that users are permitted to specialize!). So to avoid any potential for const objects being modified, there must be a clear sequencing of inserted and extracted states for any node.

There is standard wording to help with the specialization issue in [container.node.overview]p4:

> If a user-defined specialization of `pair` exists for `pair<const Key, T>` or `pair<Key, T>`, where `Key` is the
>   container’s `key_type` and `T` is the container’s `mapped_type`, the behavior of operations involving node handles is undefined.

Comment: This does not answer my question, sorry.

Comment: @Walter: I've given you exactly the rationale for disallowing the operations you asked about. Is there anything you'd like clarified?

Comment: Sorry, but I agree with Walter.  How does this explain that if I am holding a reference to a map item, I cannot change `T` while the node is extracted through that reference?

Comment: @KerrekSB 1) The mapped object is never stored as `const`. 2) I have no issue with the clear sequence, i.e. when one can alter the `key` (clearly only if its extracted from the map, requiring another type `node_handle` for only this purpose). My question related to access to the *`mapped_type` via pointers*.

Comment: If you have a reference to the map element, any access through that reference assumes that the object is const. If you persist the reference even while the object becomes mutable, mutated, and then reinserted, you would continue assuming it's const, even though it has been changed. That's a problem. It's somewhat related to doing repeated placement-new and destruction of an object with a const member.

Comment: The map element can be `const` or not, that's irrelevant here. The map element itself is not moved/copied and is never changed -- recall that my code compiled for immovable objects. AFAIK, only a pointer to it (stored in the map / node-handle) is mutable, mutated, and reinserted. I'm adding a UB scenario to the post. If you could point out what can go wrong here, that would be nice.

Comment: @Walter: As I understand, in `std::map`, you have `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, during extraction, a "new" object `std::pair<Key, Value>` replace that one, so using that old pointer is invalid (strict aliasing rule + lifetime).

Comment: @Jarod42 although this implies that the implementation "resurrects" an object whose lifetime has ended when re-inserting. Spooky

Comment: +1 This is pretty much it. These rules were specifically requested by CWG and are critical to the feature's implementability.

Answer (score 7):

I'm just following up on Kerrek SB's answer in the hope to explain the issue in more detail (and hence a bit more convincingly). The adopted [revision 3 of the paper in question (P0083R3)](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0083r3.pdf) mentions the `std::pair<const Key, Mapped>` vs `std::pair<Key, Mapped>` conundrum, and that "The conversion between these can be effected safely using a technique similar to that used by `std::launder` on extraction and reinsertion."

IOW, extraction and reinsertion are safe from optimizations related to type punning by invoking "implementation 'magic'" (this is the explicit wording in the paper) to resolve any possible aliasing problems within the container code itself, and insofar as user code abides by the restrictions you mentioned.

This raises the question of why this "magic" cannot be extended to cover also cases where user code accesses the `Mapped` element of a dissociated node through a pointer that was obtained while the node still belonged to a container. The reason for this is that the scope of implementing such "magic" is considerably greater than the scope of implementing the limited magic that applies only to node extraction and insertion.

Consider e.g., trivially, this function:

```
int f(std::pair<const int, int> &a, const std::pair<int, int> &b)
{
    a.second = 5;
    return b.second;
}
```

As per the restrictions on type aliasing, the implementation is allowed to assume that `a` and `b` cannot reside at the same memory location. Therefore, the implementation is also allowed to assume that `a.second` and `b.second` do not reside at the same memory location, *even though they have the same type*. Therefore, an implementation is entitled to some very basic code generation freedoms such as performing the load of `b.second` before the store to `a.second`, without needing to actually compare the addresses of `a` and `b` first.

Now assume that the restrictions on map splicing were not as you have mentioned. Then, it would be possible to do the following:

```
int g()
{
    std::map<int, int> m{{1, 1}};
    auto &r = m[1];
    auto node = m.extract(1);
    return f(r, node.value());
}
```

Because of the type punning restrictions, clearly this is UB. Now, hold on, I know you want to protest because:

1. The `node_type` for a `std::map` does not have a `value()` method.
2. Even if it did, the `node_type` is supposed to `std::launder` (or something roughly equivalent) the value.

However, these points do not provide an actual remedy. As far as the first point is concerned, consider this minor variation:

```
int f(std::pair<const int, int> &a, const int &b)
{
    a.second = 5;
    return b;
}

int g()
{
    std::map<int, int> m{{1, 1}};
    auto &r = m[1];
    auto node = m.extract(1);
    return f(r, node.mapped());
}
```

Now, peephole optimization into `f` does not give the compiler sufficient information to rule out aliasing. However, let's assume that the compiler is able to inline both `node.mapped()` (and therefore, the compiler can establish that it returns a reference to the `second` of a `std::pair<int, int>`), and `f`. Suddenly, the compiler may once more feel entitled to a dangerous optimization.

But what about the laundering? First of all, this does not apply here, because the information regarding `extract` and the laundering done within it may be in a different translation unit altogether than `node_type::mapped()`. This needs emphasizing: With the tight restrictions that were standardized, *the laundering can be done during extraction, it does not have to be done on every call to `value()`*, which is also clearly the intent expressed in the quote I provided at the beginning. The main issue, however, is that laundering cannot prevent UB here, even if it were done inside `node_type::mapped()`. In fact, the following code has undefined behavior (example assumes that `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(float)`):

```
float g()
{
    float value = 0.0f; // deliberate separate initialization, see below
    value = 3.14f;
    int *intp = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int *>(&value));
    *intp = 1;
    return value + *intp;
}
```

This is because *using `std::launder` does not give the user permission to type punning at all*. Instead, `std::launder` only allows reusing the memory of `value` by establishing a lifetime dependency between the `float` that lives at `&value` initially and the `int` that lives there after the `std::launder`. In fact, as far as the standard is concerned, `value` and `*intp` cannot possibly be alive at the same time precisely because they have pointer-incompatible types and the same memory location.

(What `std::launder` does achieve, here, is e.g. to prevent reordering of `value = 3.14f;` to after `*intp = 1`. Simply put, the compiler is not allowed to reorder writes to after the `std::launder`, nor reads from a laundered pointer to before the `std::launder`, unless it can prove that the memory locations do not in fact overlap, and this is true even if pointer-incompatible types are involved. I used a separate assignment so that I could make this point more clearly.)

What this finally boils down to, is that, to safely support the usage you envision, implementations would have to add *additional magic* on top of that mentioned in the paper (and the latter is largely implemented already because it is at least very similar to the effects of `std::launder`). Not only would this have caused additional effort, but it could also have had the side effect of preventing certain optimizations in cases where the user voluntarily abides by the restrictions as standardized. Judgment calls like this are made all the time in standardizing C++, or pretty much anything, where the experts try to weigh the projected costs against certain or at least probable benefits. If you still need to know more, you'd likely have to approach some of the CWG members directly, because this is where the request to apply these restrictions was made, and as mentioned in the paper linked above.

Hope this helps to clear things up a bit, even if you still disagree with the resolution taken.

As a final note, I highly recommend you to watch some of the great talks on C++ UB if you haven't already, for instance [Undefined Behavior is Awesome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehyHyAIa5so) by Piotr Padlewski, or [Garbage In, Garbage Out…](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG1OZ69H_-o) by Chandler Carruth.

Comment: Are the authors of the Standard ever going to get around to defining a directives to make "standard" C++ as semantically powerful as the `-fno-strict-aliasing` dialect?  I'd have no qualm with having to use directives to tell the compiler when I'm doing something unusual if such directives existed, but to limit the semantics of a language for the sake of "optimization" seems counter-productive.

Comment: @supercat Unsure… but, usually, the committee have left such things as unportable implementation details, e.g. strict vs. fast floating-point math, where AFAIK, no attempts were made to standardize a minimal set of "fast" behaviors, and each compiler (e.g. GCC with `-ffast-math`, or MSVC with `/fp:fast`…) has its own idea of permissible/desired behavior if fast math is enabled. They don't tend to increase strictness a lot in general… one of the strongest examples I can think of is changing the evaluation order of function arguments from unsequenced to indeterminately sequenced.

Comment: I find evaluation-order change curious, actually.  It certainly make sense to mandate a guarantee that if the right-hand side operand of `=` throws an exception, the left will not have had any side-effects, but prior to C++17, an assignment like `*getPointer() = someGlobal;` could be processed more efficiently as "call getPointer; load someGlobal; store the value to the pointer" than via the C++17-required "load someGlobal; push value; call getPointer; pop value; store value to pointer".

Comment: A big problem with both the C Standard, which seems to bleed into C++, is that the authors aren't clear on whether they are trying to define a core language which implementations intended for various purposes would be expected to extend as needed to serve those purposes, or whether it is trying to define a language which is expected to be capable of serving most purposes without extension.  Either could be useful if the authors were clear and consistent about what they were defining, but the lack of clarity has lead to worst-of-both-worlds consequences.